# How do I transfer simple parameter from one ASP.Net page to another?

Tags: asp.net

In the course I'm taking they taught me to use Response.Redirect like this:

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("name.aspx?sb="+bts+"&del="+delimiter));
```

Is there a better way to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specifically what you are discussing is the means to transfer state between pages. That can be done in an handful of ways:

1. Query string parameters. This is the equivalent of what you have done in your post.
2. Session. In this scenario, you would populate a Session variable on one page and then retrieve it on the other.
3. Cookies.
4. Form variables if you post directly to the page in question.

Comment: Viewstate is for postbacks to the same form.  I don't believe it would be an option for persisting a value to another page.  Session would be the right choice of the two for that.

Comment: @nycdan - You can use ViewState if you post directly to the target form instead of using the default postback behavior.

Comment: Is crafting the URL manually with string.Format() the correct way to do this?

Comment: BTW, specifically right now I'm interested in query string parameters.

Comment: @Greg, @nycdan - Have revised the form variable item to remove ViewState.

Comment: @DaliH - Is your question "what is the best way to transfer information between pages" or is it "what is the best way to assemble a query string with parameters"?

Comment: Thomas, I wasn't aware of the cross-page postback behavior.  Not sure when that would be useful yet, but I'm happy to learn something new.  Thanks.

Comment: @nycdan - Posts to another page was (still is in some cases) a common way to pass information beyond the query string and session. It was very common in the Asp Classic days. When .NET came out, it instilled the idea of using postbacks instead of cross posts.

Answer (score 3):

See [How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx).

In addition you can also use the [`HttpContext.Current.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx) collection to pass data if you are performing a Server.Transfer instead of a Response.Redirect.

Also, the code snippet:

- Is just performing string concatenation so you don't need to call string.Format.
- Should UrlEncode query string parameters

e.g.

```
Response.Redirect("name.aspx?sb=" + Server.UrlEncode(bts) 
    + "&del=" + Server.UrlEncode(delimiter));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several different ways to allow information to be sent across multiple pages.

1. Query String parameters.  (like your example)
2. Session variables
3. Cookies
4. form variables (when posting to a different page)

It's really up to you which one to use.

Query string is usually easy, I use those when the landing page is the only thing needing the data.

Session requires you to have a session provider defined and to make some decisions regarding, in process, out of process, etc.  Also this will keep the data around until either session expires or you explicitly clear it.

Cookies are good, bear in mind all cookies can be viewed by the client.

Form variables for cross form posting is probably the rarest one and comes with it's own caveats to make sure .net accepts this.

Answer (score 0):

If the link depends on information you know on Page Load, rather than information entered by the user during a postback, I would generate the link upfront.

```
MyHyperlink.NavigateUrl = "name.aspx?sb="+bts+"&del="+delimiter;
```

That way the client doesn't have to round-trip to the server to learn what address to redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

As @Thomas mentions, there are a number of ways to do what you're asking.

1. Query string params:  Easy, and should be used if at all possible.  You can have multiple tabs/browsers open without affecting each other.
2. Session.  This seems easy, but it falls down when you have the potential for having multiple tabs open, since you only have a single session object.  I've seen applications corrupt data:  open tab, load object into session. Open 2nd tab, 2nd object replaces 1st object in session.  Go back to 1st tab, make a change, click save: boom, 2nd object gets properties of 1st.
3. I can't think of a single reason for ever using this - all the limitation of the session, with none of the benefits.
4. Form Variables:  You can post to a different page, and there are situation where you'd want to use this, but generally this is going to add complexity where it's not needed, especially in asp.net - viewstate, etc could cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding another answer because it's possible everyone here missed your real question.

If the real question is: what is the best way to assemble a string for querystring parameters then you should use:

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("name.aspx?sb={0}&del={1}", bts, delimiter));
```

This allows you to have the string itself constructed and the format method will inject the parameters at the defined positions.